# What is the smallest $5$-vertex-connected ($5$-edge-connected) planar graph?

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness, planar-graphs

A planar graph cannot be $6$-connected because the number of edges of a planar
graph with $n$ vertices is at most $3n-6$, while a $6$-connected graph with $n$ vertices
must have at least $3n$ edges.

- Are there $5$-vertex-connected planar graphs, and if yes, what is the smallest ?
- Is there an even smaller example for a $5$-edge-connected planar graph ?

  Since a $5$-connected graph with n vertices must have at least $\frac{5n}{2}$ edges,
  the condition is $\frac{5n}{2}\le 3n-6$, which implies $n\ge 12$, so a $5$-connected
  planar graph must have at least $12$ vertices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [icosahedral graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IcosahedralGraph.html) (the graph of the vertices and edges of an icosahedron) is a 5-vertex-connected, and 5-edge-connected, planar graph. It has 12 vertices and 30 edges. Due to the bounds you mention in the question, it is the smallest possible example.